# FacetWP - how to put custom order by

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, facetwp

I create custom fields using Pods Admin and FacetWP do show and filter on page.

but I need to change "order by" to custom field called "volta-rapida-tempo".

Like this:

```
<?php
    return array(
      "post_type" => "volta_rapida",
      "post_status" => "publish",
      "orderby" => "volta-rapida-tempo",
      "order" => "ASC",
      "posts_per_page" => 10
    );
```

How can I do this correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes first change **orderby** with `meta_value` and add `meta_key` Please check below code for the same.

```
 <?php
    return array(
    "post_type" => "volta_rapida",
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "meta_key" => "volta-rapida-tempo",
    "orderby"           => "meta_value",
    "order" => "ASC",
    "posts_per_page" => 10
  );
```